# Changing the state isn't rendered in the UI

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx, react-props, react-state

I'm new in React so i faced this problem and i don't understand why this is happening , I created Component called ShoppingCart which display all the products that i added to the cart:
ShoppingCart.jsx file:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Product from './Product';
class ShoppingCart extends Component{
    state={
        products:[
            {
                id:1,
                name:"Burger",
                count:2
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name:"Cola",
                count:3
            },
            {
                id:3,
                name:"Fries",
                count:4
            }
        ]
    }
    deleteProduct=(product)=>{
        let newProducts = this.state.products.filter((p)=>
            { return p.id !== product.id}
        );
        this.setState({products:newProducts});
    }
    reset = ()=>{
        let resetProducts = this.state.products.map((p)=>
            { p.count = 0; return p}
        );
        console.log(resetProducts);
        this.setState({products:resetProducts});
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>

            <h1>Products</h1>
            <button onClick={this.reset}>reset</button>
            {this.state.products.map((product)=>{
                return <Product key={product.id} onDelete={this.deleteProduct} product={product}/>
            })}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default ShoppingCart;
```

and i have function to delete element from the shopping cart and function to reset the counter of the products in the shopping cart
also i have component called Product holds the product details such as : id,name and the counter:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Product extends Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.product.id,
        name: this.props.product.name,
        count: this.props.product.count
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <span>{this.state.name}</span>
                <span>{this.state.count}</span>
                <button onClick = {()=>this.props.onDelete(this.props.product)}>Delete</button>
                {/* Ensure onDelete is used correctly */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

 
export default Product;
```

Now my problem is when i try to delete any product it is deleted and the new list of items is rendered in the page but when i try to reset the counter of the elements it is reset but the new list isn't rendered to the page.
So can someone help me to understand how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code I put together which I think is inline with what you've included in your original question:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const initialState = {
products:[
        {
            id:1,
            name:"Burger",
            count:2
        },
        {
            id:2,
            name:"Cola",
            count:3
        },
        {
            id:3,
            name:"Fries",
            count:4
        }
    ]
};


function Products(){

const [items, setItems] = useState(initialState)
const deleteItem = (itemId) => { 
    const filteredArray = items.products.filter((x) =>  x.id !== itemId)
    setItems({products: filteredArray})
}

return (
    <div>
        <p>Product list:</p>
        <ul>
            {items.products.map((val,idx) => {
                return(
                <li key={val.id}>
                    {val.name}
                    <button onClick={() => deleteItem(val.id)}>Delete</button>
                </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>);
}

export default Products;
```

Also, here is **another example** of a similar behaviour, maybe this can be of some help:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-remove-item-from-list/